SwiftUI: prevent dropping a file on a TextField
By default, a SwiftUI TextField inserts the string value of the file path when a file is dropped on it.
How do you reject items dropped on a SwiftUI TextField? (Disabling the text field is not an option. One must still be able to paste or type text into it.)

On macOS, you can overlay the text field with another dropDestination view, so that whatever is dropped goes to that view.
TextField("Foo", text: $text)
    .overlay {
        Color.clear
            .dropDestination(for: String.self) { _, _ in
                false
            }
    }

By using a transparent view like Color.clear, you still allow other user interactions on the text field.
Dragging a file over the text field will not even show the "+" sign, because it is not a String. Dragging some text over it would show the "+" sign, but dropping the text will not do anything. If you want it to change the text, it is trivial to do so.
The same technique also works with the older onDrop modifier. You can pass an empty array of UTTypes, so nothing can be dropped.
.onDrop(of: [UTType](), isTargeted: nil) { _ in false }


The overlay suggestion works, but seems a bit too kludgy. There should be a direct way of modifying a TextField's onDrop behavior. Perhaps I misunderstand your suggestion about the "older onDrop" functionality: with Sonoma 14.5, it doesn't prevent dropping a file onto a TextField which already contains text from inserting the string value of the file path at the drop location. Were you saying "in previous (unspecified) macOS versions, onDrop(of: [UTType](), isTargeted: nil) { _ in false } works, but doesn't now?

@pfurbacher no I just meant that onDrop is introduced earlier than dropDestination, i.e. it is available in more versions. Both modifiers work for me on macOS 14.1, so perhaps something changed between versions. And forget about “directly” modifying things in SwiftUI. Very few views allow you to have such fine-grained control. You can probably wrap an NSTextField to do this, but I’m not familiar enough with AppKit to tell you how.

This is what I found from a quick google.

Maybe poor choice of the word, "directly". What I meant was TextField.onDrop is "directly modifying TextField (e.g., onDrop)", instead of having to overlay with a view which essentially steals the drop. Since your overlay answer works, I have accepted it as the (good enough) answer.

One more thing: for the TextField.onDrop approach, can you test with Sonoma 14.1, if you already have some text in the TextField, and you drop a file onto it, that it does not insert the textual representation of the file? In 14.5, if no text is present, the drop is rejected; if text is present: drop inserts the file path. It is when some text is already present in the TextField and dropping inserts at the drop location which prompted my original question. When the TextField is empty, the drop was rejected, as I would have expected using TextField.onDrop(...) { _ in false }.

@pfurbacher Oh you made onDrop directly modify TextField? I meant to say that replacing dropDestination with onDrop works too. In both approaches, the modifier is modifying Color.clear.
